# JQuery Multidimensional Array - make one column comma separated if duplicate value present

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a Multidimensional array called Submission like

```
Submission.push({ 
    "Title": Title, 
    "Rev": "", 
    "ReviewingOrgs": AssignedOrganization, 
    "DaysOpen": "",
    "DueDate": "",
    "DocURL":"" 
});
```

After this array is populated the resulting array has values like,

```
Title     Rev   Reviewing Orgs      days Open   Due
Sub1    1      Org1      8    31-Oct-2014
Sub1    1      Org2      8    31-Oct-2014
Sub2    1      Org1      13   21-Nov-2014
```

Can anyone help me to modify this array to give resulting array like below using jQuery?

```
Title   Rev     Reviewing Orgs           days Open      Due
Sub1    1      Org1 ,Org2  8 31-Oct-2014
Sub2    1      Org1       13 21-Nov-2014
```

i.e. I want to check if same title value exists in the array make the 'reviewing org' column comma separated and delete that duplicate row. FYI Values of same title rows have same values in all columns except ‘reviewing org’ column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution assumes that there may be multiple duplicate rows.

```
var l = Submission.length;
for (var act, i = 0; i < l, i++) { // iterate over Submission array
    act = Submission[i]; // get actual item
    for (var j = i + 1; j < l; j++) { // start search for double at next position
        if (act.Title == Submission[j].Title) { // when a double found
            act.ReviewingOrgs += ',' + submission[j].ReviewingOrgs; // add org to the orgs of actual item
            Submission.splice(j, 1); l--; // snip out double, decrease array length
        }
    }
}
```